# Parametized SQL query on a loop not updating correctly

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I have an sql query running on a loop. There are two values FINGER and index_str that both need to be updated in parallel.

```
FINGER: (numpy array)
[['1012_8']
 ['10214_5']
 ['10409_9']
```

```
index_str: (pandas dataframe)
0      14,38,51,65,84,85
1       3,34,58,65,66,75
2      3,15,68,70,80,82
```

Above are the first 3 examples. There are over 1000 of each in reality.

```
for i in range(len(FINGER)):
    print i
    print FINGER[i]
    for x in index_str[i]:
        yy = FINGER[i][0]
        #print range(len(FINGER))
        index_str = str(x)
        query = "SELECT finger, ind, x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UNIL_fingerprints where finger = '" + yy + "' and ind IN (" + index_str + ") order by ind "
        print query
        c.execute(query)
        rows = c.fetchall()
        print rows
```

Above is the loop and query in question.

So far the loop runs through all values of index_str for only the first FINGER value. To elaborate, the query updates for the first 3 examples as follows.

```
SELECT finger, ind, x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UNIL_fingerprints where finger = '1012_8' and ind IN (14,38,51,65,84,85) order by ind 

SELECT finger, ind, x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UNIL_fingerprints where finger = '1012_8' and ind IN (3,34,58,65,66,75) order by ind 

SELECT finger, ind, x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UNIL_fingerprints where finger = '1012_8' and ind IN (3,15,68,70,80,82) order by ind
```

Whereas '1012_8' should be '10214_5' and '10409_9' respectively in the 2nd and 3rd query above.

Any ideas on how to get this to update properly would be helpful.

Comment: try this: "SELECT finger, ind, x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UNIL_fingerprints where finger = '" + yy + "' and ind IN ('" + index_str + "') order by ind "                or you can try                                "SELECT finger, ind, x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UNIL_fingerprints where finger = '{0}' and ind IN ('{1}') order by ind".format(yy,index_str)

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

You want `zip()`:

```
for finger, indexes in zip(FINGERS, index_str):
   print("fingers : {}- indexes: {}".format(finger, indexes))
```

Also you REALLY want to learn and [use the db-api properly](https://bobby-tables.com/python) (well, unless you dont mind being hacked, that is).